# Override toString of internal object

Tags: java, jackson, tostring, objectmapper, jackson-databind

I have overridden toString() of an object called **Skeleton**, so when I call toString() the color variable is excluded.

```
public class Skeleton
{
    private List bones;
    private Color color;

    //  getters & setters

    @Override
    public String toString() 
    {
        String s = null;

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.setAnnotationIntrospector(new JacksonAnnotationIntrospector(){
        @Override
        public boolean hasIgnoreMarker(final AnnotatedMember m) {
                List<String> exclusions = Arrays.asList("color");
                return exclusions.contains(m.getName())|| super.hasIgnoreMarker(m);
            }
        });

        try 
        {
            s = mapper.writeValueAsString(this);

        } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return s;
    }
}
```

However, when I add a **Skeleton** object as a variable to an object called **Body** and call toString() on Body the **color** field of Skeleton is included.

```
public class Body
{
    private Skeleton skeleton = ....
```

Does anyone have any idea how to make Body use the overridden toString() method in Skeleton?

Comment: ...override `toString()` in `Body`?

Comment: The problem of course being the (probable) use of ObjectMapper in `Body.toString` by-passing `Skeleton.toString`. As ObjectMapper is expensive too, its usage is questionable. The least change would be to substitute `toString` by an interface with `represent(ObjectMapper, StringWriter)` or such, to walk an entire object hierarchy with one object mapper.

Comment: See this, https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-ignore-properties-on-serialization, check Section `5. Ignore Fields Using Filters`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to override the `toString()` method of the Body class and include whatever details you deem necessary. Include the `toString()` method of the instance variable `private Skeleton skeleton = ...` and all other member variables that you may have in the `Body` class.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of manually excluding fields in the `toString` method, which can be tedious and error-prone if other fields need to be excluded (or if `color` should no longer be excluded), you can use the Jackson [`@JsonIgnore`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.5/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonIgnore.html) annotation. Then the `toString` method in `Skeleton` can be overridden to print the serialized string:

```
public class Skeleton {

    private List bones;

    @JsonIgnore
    private Color color;

    @Override
    public String toString() {

        try {
            ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
            return mapper.writeValueAsString(this);
        } 
        catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

As mentioned in the comments, using an `ObjectMapper` to serialize an object into a `String` can be expensive if the `toString` method of `Skeleton` is frequently used. If performance becomes an issue, the `ObjectMapper` should only be used to serialize the top-most object (i.e. `Body`), rather than at each intermediary object (i.e. `Skeleton`):

```
public class Skeleton {

    private List bones;

    @JsonIgnore
    private Color color;

    // Getters & setters
}

public class Body {

    private Skeleton skeleton;

    @Override
    public String toString() {

        try {
            ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
            return mapper.writeValueAsString(this);
        } 
        catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

---

**Edit based on OP's Feedback**

In the case that you want to ignore a field only for a specific `ObjectMapper`, you can create a `SimpleBeanPropertyFilter` and specify the name of the field to ignore:

```
public class Skeleton {

    private List bones;
    private Color color;

    @Override
    public String toString() {

        try {
            ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
            FilterProvider filters = new SimpleFilterProvider()
                .addFilter("ignoreColor", SimpleBeanPropertyFilter.serializeAllExcept("color"));
            return mapper.writer(filters).writeValueAsString(this);
        } 
        catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

For more information, see **Section 5: Ignore Fields Using Filters** on [Jackson Ignore Properties on Marshalling](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-ignore-properties-on-serialization).

Comment: Unfortunately the above approach works a little too well. If I use the @JsonIgnore annotation the associated field is completely removed when I convert the Java object to a JSON object and send it over the wire. I need to keep the field but just exclude it when I call toString() on the Java object, manual exclusion seems to allow this. By any chance do you know how to manually exclude a field of an internal object?

Comment: @T-Pane Now I understand. I misunderstood your original issue. I have updated the answer above to include a section that addresses your comment.